# Angular2 with Haml

Tags: angular, haml, angular-cli

Is it possible to use HAML as template engine in Angular 2?

In Angular 2 (version `2.3.1`) you can use scss/sass instead of css. This is a given option by `angular-cli` with `--style`. For templates the cli only allows to change between inline template by setting `--inline-template`.

Unless it is supported, how do I have to configure my Angular 2 App (created by the angular-cli version `1.0.0-beta.26`) to write `HAML`, compile it to `HTML` and use the `HTML` in the `component` as a `templateUrl`?

**EDIT**
Angular/cli uses webpack. I do not know how to configure `webpack` to render haml to html before everything will be bundled.
How do I use `haml-loader` inside of Angular?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible. If you are using angular-cli you will first need to get access to the **webpack.config.js** file. You can do this by typing

```
$ ng eject
```

This will expose the config file, which you need to edit. Notice that after this you will need to start your server with "npm start" instead of "ng serve".

For haml you can use the [haml-haml-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/haml-haml-loader)

```
npm install haml-haml-loader --save-dev
```

Then under your module rules in the **webpack.config.js** file add the following rule:

```js
module: {
  rules: [
    ...
    {
      test: /\.haml$/, 
      loaders: ['haml-haml-loader']
    },
    ...
```

Finally modify your component to use your "haml" file in the following way:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: require('./app.component.haml'),
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass'],
})
```

Alternatively you can use

```
templateUrl: './app.component.haml',
```

This should get you up and running with haml

Comment: have you tried? I'm concerned that HAML will interfere with Angular's template syntax and preprocess away structural directives

Comment: Yes I have tried and it works very well. Structural directives are not an issue per se. The only cases where I revert to HTML are directives without an associated value, for example: <div *ngSwitchDefault>Something</div> or <div #something></div>. But since the haml-haml-loader allows for ordinary html in the haml templates it's not really an issue for me. HAML syntax like %div{ *ngFor: "let item of items" }, etc. works fine.

Comment: How about attribute binding?  e.g. <div #idDiv [attr.width]="this.DivWidth"/> ?

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible but only with external template files(`templateUrl`). You have to set up your building system(webpack, gulp) to preprocess all templates before they will be used by angular

Comment: It should be, does not answer how I have to configure it, to do it