# HAML in Angular 2/4?

Tags: angular, haml

We have been using [HAML](http://haml.info) with Ruby on Rails and Angular.js (1.x), but now we are migrating our app to Angular 2/4 and would like to continue using HAML for the templates. So far we could not find any example of this. We could use other template standard (like [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/)), if HAML is not a viable option going forward. Any pointers and examples are really appreciated.

Comment: You can use haml with angular2. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/42954891/285373.

Comment: No you cannot use haml here if you are using @angular/cli.
If you want to use something similar to slim look for Pug (Jade engine renamed)

Comment: @adail Any update on this? I am also facing same issue.

Comment: Sorry @AnandGargate, I'm not doing that anymore. Good luck!

Answer (score -4):

`CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` will let you to add custom html elements like haml or other else it(angular 2) will give you `template parse error`

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { CustomComponent } from './custom.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ CustomComponent ],
  exports: [ CustomComponent ],
  imports: [ CommonModule ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class CustomModule {}
```

Comment: That does not answer the question, sorry... HAML is a templating system, or an HTML pre-processor if you prefer, not a custom element...