# Webpack custom loader doesn't seem to be working (for haml-haml-loader)

Tags: angular, webpack, haml

Pretty new to running my own Angular apps. I'm using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41834019/angular2-with-haml) to set up haml loading through webpack, but it's very old and ngx doesn't support eject anymore, so I'm trying with [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-builders/custom-webpack) for some custom webpack configs.

I'm getting this error when I compile:

```
ERROR in Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> %header
|   test
```

Here's the section of my angular.json relating to the custom webpack:

```js
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
      "options": {
        "customWebpackConfig": {
          "path": "./extra-webpack.config.js",
          "mergeStrategies": {
            "externals": "replace"
          }
        },
```

And the extra-webpack.config.js:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        { test: /\.haml$/, loader: 'haml-haml' }
      ]
    }
};
```

Edit: not sure how to set up a fiddle or stackblitz for this, but I have a fresh repo that replicates the problem: https://github.com/jugglervr/haml-test

Comment: Your implementation looks right. Can you try setup and share a small repo which can replicable?

Comment: repo set up and linked in min question. thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you missed to setup the package `@angular-builders/dev-server` to serve your app. Here is the the step to make it work again:

Install it:

```sh
npm i -D @angular-builders/dev-server
```

Also in angular.json, replace value of build property from @angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server to @angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server under serve block:

```js
"serve": {
  "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
}
```

Final note: it looks like webpack no longer allows to omit `loader` as we specify our loader, so append the loader in your webpack config:

```js
{ test: /\.haml$/, loader: 'haml-haml-loader' }
```

Comment: Looks like that was it. I noodled around with dev-server but it was confusing so I felt more like I was flailing. I think I had added it to build instead of serve. Thanks so much!!